# How to integrate a web application with google for my domain?

Tags: google-apps

I have a web application that's going to be available for all users on my google domain.

Is there a way of allowing the application to manage user's emails, calendar, etc without requiring the user authorization using the fact that all users are part of the domain?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to have a look into Google Apps 2-Legged OAuth APIs, they will allow you to access/manipulate users data without their authorization.

You can find the list of available 2-Legged OAuth APIs [here](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=162106&topic=2759255&ctx=topic).

Unfortunately you will see that you cannot do as much with the 2-Legged API as you can with the 3-Legged API. However, 3-Legged OAuth requires the users consent at least once.